# Jupyter Lab Syntax Highlighting isn't Working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, syntax-highlighting, jupyter-lab

I'm using the default Jupyter Lab that comes with the installation of Anaconda.  Recently, it has started removing all syntax highlighting, where before the syntax was completely colorized.  I currently have two notebooks open, one with colorization and the other gray, and I can't seem to figure out why one would lose all the highlighting.  This has been an ongoing issue for about a week, and I can't seem to find any answers online that work.

Things I've tried:

1. Reverting to a previous version of Jupyter Lab
2. Reverting to a previous version of Anaconda via `conda install --revision 1`
3. Switching to the default Jupyter themes
4. Restarting kernels
5. Restarting the computer
6. Re-installing theme packages

Comment: Please add a screenshot, name and version of the kernel that you are using (IPython? IRKernel? IJulia?) and any messages from the [browser console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console). Also the name and version of your browser.

Comment: It's a Python 3 Kernel.  There's no weird messages in the browser console, just regular running messages.  I'm using Chrome Version 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 3):

In my case what I did was a simple refresh in Chrome once the notebook opens then the colorization happens.